# Lottie web image sequence - start animation after loading images

Tags: javascript, html, lottie

I am using Airbnb's Lottie to create an animation from jpg sequence that plays when the page is loaded. Problem is that the animation starts as soon as the webpage opens, but it seems that by the time the images load the animation is already in half or even at the end. What is the best way to handle this, so that user sees the animation from the beginning?

I've tried using both `DOMLoaded` and `data_ready` event listening, but neither of them seem to fix the problem.

Currently my code is as follows:

```
      var params = {
        container: document.getElementById('hero-anim'),
        animationData: animationData,
        renderer: 'svg',
        loop: false,
        autoplay: false,
      };

      var anim = lottie.loadAnimation(params);
      anim.addEventListener('DOMLoaded', lottie.play());
```

Website where this is used: test.romancecapsule.com

Any ideas on how to fix this, please? Also one more problem I am running into is in Firefox (mac, v70.0.1) where it is flickers white between each image.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

you can use [jiagra](https://github.com/samyk/jiagra) to prefetch the images of your code.

download and import the js library onto your code. then prefetch the images that you want to load before.

```
<script src="jiagra.js"></script>
...
<link rel="prefetch"  href="/images/animation_frame1.jpeg">
```

Read more about [Chrome Prerendering](http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/prerender.html):

Read more about [Firefox Prefetching](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Link_prefetching_FAQ):

Comment: Thank you for reply. Does prefetching solve my issue though? As I will be using the animation on top of my homepage?

Answer (score 0):

Lottie has `loaded_images` event which is triggered when all image loads have either succeeded or failed.
You can use it as:

```
anim.addEventListener('loaded_images', lottie.play());
```

in your code. Is should solve your issue.